# Gmail Quota Reached in AppMaker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have an app that's running as a developer. I'm currently reaching Gmail quota due to notifications sent to users, it's an approval app which sends the status to all approvers. Is there a way that I can either increase Gmail quota via GCP or use another email platform to send emails such as Amazon SES within appmaker? Need your advice on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't increase the quota for `GmailApp`. You can increase the quota for the Gmail API. From your question we don't know which you are using.

Comment: When you say 'sends the status to all approvers', are you referring to when 1 status changes it sends an individual email to each approver as in status changes and it sends 10 emails (one for each approver), or do you send 1 email to lets say all 10 approvers so they all get the same email?